# When does strict inclusion holds for the domain of subdifferential?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Recall that, given an extended real-valued function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to (-\infty, \infty]$

Its effective domain is,
$$\text{dom}(f) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) < +\infty\}$$

The subdifferential is, $$\partial f(x) = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n: f(x^\prime) \geq f(x) + v^\top (x^\prime - x), \forall x^\prime \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$

and its effective domain is all the vectors where it is subdifferentiable,

$$\text{dom}(\partial f) =  \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \partial f(x) \neq \varnothing\}.$$

Now by a theorem of Rockafellar (top of page 227, "Convex Analysis", 1970), it states,

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to (-\infty, \infty]$ be a closed, proper, convex function, then $$\text{rint}(\text{dom}(f))) \subseteq \text{dom}(\partial f) \subseteq \text{dom}(f).$$
where $\text{rint}$ is the relative interior.

---

**My question is, when does strict inclusion holds, especially for** $\text{dom}(\partial f) \subseteq \text{dom}(f)$.

---

For any set I can think of that is closed, you can make a point on the boundary of that set, and there will exist some subgradient at that point. There is the possibility that this strict inequality is an equality for most cases.

Comment: You seem to have posted this twice. Please remove one of the copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by letting $f(x):=-\sqrt x$ if $x\ge0$ and  $f(x):=\infty$ if $x<0$. Then $f$ is a [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_convex_function) [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_convex_function) convex function.

However, $f(0)=0<\infty$, so that $0\in\text{dom}(f)$. On the other hand, $f(y)=-\sqrt y<vy=f(0)+v(y-0)$ for each real $v$ and any small enough $y>0$. So, $0\notin\text{dom}(\partial f)$.

Thus, here the set inclusion $\text{dom}(\partial f)\subset\text{dom}(f)$ is strict.

Comment: The example has now been replaced by a slightly simpler one. A few details have been added.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems if it goes towards the boundary too "sharp" then there won't be a subdifferential at the boundary

Comment: I wonder if it is simpler to just make the observation that $f(x) = -\sqrt(x) + \delta_{x \geq 0}(x)$, so $\partial f(x) = -\frac{1}{2} x^{-1/2} +N_{x \geq 0}(x)$ and the first term is not defined at $x = 0$.

Comment: @ShamisenExpert : Your latter expression for the subdifferential will not work -- for one, the subdifferential of a function at a point is, not a number, but a set.

Comment: We can always write $\{-\frac{1}{2} x^{-1/2}\}$ as a singleton set. This is what I meant. The value in this set is not defined as $x \to 0$. Is this a simpler way to see that this inclusion is strict?

Comment: @ShamisenExpert : Even if you have a correct expression for the subdifferential at $x>0$ and that expression is only defined for $x>0$, that by itself does not imply anything about the subdifferential at $x=0$. Anyhow, I believe the existing answer is as simple as it can possibly be. However, you can of course give your own **full-fledged** answer. Then, if you wish, I could comment on that.

Comment: @ShamisenExpert : Perhaps this will make the answer more intuitive: If a one-sided directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ is $-\infty$, then (reasoning as in the above answer) we can show that the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ is empty. In the given example, the right derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ is $-\infty$, and hence the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ is empty.

Comment: I meant "and hence the subdifferential of $f$ at $x=0$ is empty."